# network path to a file stored in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, file, sharepoint, relative-path, filepath

I know with SharePoint I can use a file explorer to look at the files and folders stored in the database, can I do the same for files stored in a database for my own web application?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't.

All the data is stored in MDF files, or `filestream` files.